# Difference between factory_girl and factory_girl_rails Ruby Gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

Is there a difference between `factory_girl` and `factory_girl_rails` Ruby Gems? I have a recurring problem with an error in RSpec Testing: "uninitialized constant FactoryGirl (NameError)".

Somebody told me that there is a difference between the two (this is really confusing) and one needs the other to work or something along those lines?

My spec_helper file has both:

```
require 'factory_girl'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
```

My Gemfile has:

```
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
```

Here is the full error:

```
uninitialized constant FactoryGirl (NameError)
    from /srv/homes/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
    from /srv/homes/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /srv/homes/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
    from /srv/homes/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
    from /srv/homes/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /srv/homes/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /srv/homes/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
****@epi-stu-hut-shell3:~/projects/project4/spec/factories$
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error. Share the relevant code?

Answer (score 5):

You only need:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
end
```

because factory_girl_rails automatically incorporates the factory_girl gem and adds support for Rails.

These gems go in both test and development groups because Rails generators will create stub files in development and of course they are needed in the test environment.

There's no need to add factory_girl or factory_girl_rails to your specs/spec_helper.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

Add `factory_girl_rails` to your Gemfile under `test` group

```
group :test, :development do
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
end
```

then do NOT do a require in spec_helper, it should get loaded automatically during tests; use `bundle exec` if needed when running rspec