# What is the difference between the factory_bot and the factory_bot_rails gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, factory-bot

I inherited a codebase for a Rails application that uses the  `factory_bot` gem instead of `factory_bot_rails`.

What is the difference between the two gems?
Should I change the gem in the Gemfile from `factory_bot` to `factory_bot_rails` ?

There is a previous entry with a similar title but it doesn't answer any of the questions made above
[Difference between factory_girl and factory_girl_rails Ruby Gems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865256/difference-between-factory-girl-and-factory-girl-rails-ruby-gems)

I also found this but it doesn't give me an answer either
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/issues/1118

Comment: factory_bot_rails adds Rails integration to factory_bot

Comment: The project was named factory_girl until 2017 so that other question is very much relevant and almost a dup target.

Answer (score 3):

`factory_bot_rails` just provides your app with Rails-specific `factory_bot` integrations. So yes, you should change the gem in the Gemfile to be `factory_bot_rails`. `factory_bot_rails` will automatically include `factory_bot` as well.